# Socket.io - Socket server doesn't console anything- has been blocked by CORS policy: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains the invalid value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

### I'm building a forum site where two users after connecting can post a status then comment on them. For comments, i used socket.io .

However, whenever i successfully connect (login) to my forum, i notice that socket server doesn't console anything. Meanwhile i'm expecting in console this message `A new user is connected !` .

I'm not sure if i did something wrong in my codes, so here they are:

---

I installed **express**, **nodemon** and **socket.io** in my socket server:

- **Socket server:**

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "socket",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.3",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
  "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(4000, {
cors: {
    origin: "http//localhost:3000",
},
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A new user is connected !');
})
io.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('User has left !');
});
```

---

- **Front:**

Also i installed **socket.io-client** in client (front), then in my web page, i added this code :

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
export default () => {

  //implement socket
  const socket = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
      socket.current = io("ws://localhost:4000")
  }, [])

return (
  //some html code
)
}
```

---

- **Console dev errors:**
- **Console tab:**

F12 Console shows theses errors every ~4 seconds:

```
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/? 
    EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O09cPlb' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by 
    CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 
    'http//localhost:3000'.
```

- **Netword tab:**

Shows the same Status each ~4 seconds in red : **CORS error**

---

- **My project tree:**

  ```
   Project Forum
   ├── back     
   ├── client
      └──index.jsx
   └── socket
      └──package.json
      └──app.js
  ```

---

- **Console Visual Studio Code:**

Visual studio code's console always shows this **only** how many times i refresh browser or ctrl+S  (save) the code:

```
[nodemon] starting 'node apde app.js'
```

I tried to delete cookies from Application in Console dev, clear cache, logout and login back, but none fixed my problem.

Comment: There is a colon missing in `http//localhost:3000`, making this value invalid. It's a typo in your `app.js`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen i dont see the typo error you are talking about in `app.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.js`

```js
cors: {
    origin: "http//localhost:3000",
}
```

should be

```js
cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the cors plugin to your node.js backend using 
`npm i cors`

Require it in your node `main.js` file and implement it as follows:

```
let express = require('express');
let cors = require('cors');
let app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

If you don't want to install a plugin add the following code to your `main.js` file in your node backend.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
   next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` instead of `localhost`

```
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
```